# Divisão entre funções postgresql

Tags: postgresql

tenho duas funções que, quando executadas separadamente, me retornam valores sem problema. Acontece que preciso dividir uma pela outra mas não está dando certo.

```
Função 1
select getestoque(array[19480000001], array[19480000001], '2019-03-01')

Retorno
183

Função 2
select avg(pel_area) from getarea(array[19480000001,19480000002], array[19480000001, 19480000002], '2019-03-01')

Retorno
75.000
```

Outro detalhe, essa divisão precisa ser feita dentro de uma 3ª função, estou fazendo da seguinte maneira:

```
Função 3
create or replace function getLotacao(fazenda bigint[], retiro bigint[], dataLot date, intervalo bigint)
returns 
table (
    totalCabecas integer,
    pesoTotal decimal(18, 6),
    UA decimal(15, 6),
    pesoMedio decimal(18, 6),
    valorMedio decimal(18, 6),
    total decimal(18, 6),
    areaHec decimal(18, 6),
    cabHec decimal(18, 6), 
    UAHA decimal(18, 6),
    areaAql decimal(18, 6),
    cabAlq decimal(18, 6), 
    UAAlq decimal(18, 6)
) as $$
declare
begin   
    for i in 0..$4 -1 loop
    return query 
    select getestoque($1, $2, $3::date + 1 * i),
           getpesolotacao($1, $2, $3::date + 1 * i),
           getpesolotacao($1, $2, $3::date + 1 * i) / 450,
           getpesolotacao($1, $2, $3::date + 1 * i) / getestoque($1, $2, $3::date + 1 * i),
           getvalorlotacao($1, $3::date + 1 * i) / getestoque($1, $2, $3::date + 1 * i),
           getpesolotacao($1, $2, $3::date + 1 * i) * (getvalorlotacao($1, $3::date + 1 * i) / getestoque($1, $2, $3::date + 1 * i)),
           avg(pel_area) from getarea($1, $2, $3::date + 1 * i),
           getestoque($1, $2, $3::date + 1 * i) / avg(pel_area) from getarea($1, $2, $3::date + 1 * i),
           **(getpesolotacao($1, $2, $3::date + 1 * i) / 450) / avg(pel_area) from getarea($1, $2, $3::date + 1 * i)**,
           avg(pel_area) from getarea($1, $2, $3::date + 1 * i) / 2.4,
           getestoque($1, $2, $3::date + 1 * i) / (avg(pel_area) from getarea($1, $2, $3::date + 1 * i) / 2.4),
           (getpesolotacao($1, $2, $3::date + 1 * i) / 450) / (avg(pel_area) from getarea($1, $2, $3::date + 1 * i) / 2.4);                                                                                                       
    end loop;                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

O problema está em:

```
**(getpesolotacao($1, $2, $3::date + 1 * i) / 450) / avg(pel_area) from getarea($1, $2, $3::date + 1 * i)**,
```

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "/"
LINE 28:      getestoque($1, $2, $3::date + 1 * i) / avg(pel_area) fr...

Mas não está dando certo, podem me ajudar por favor?

Obrigado.

Comment: Estranho estas múltiplas cláusulas FROM dentro do mesmo SELECT.

Answer (score 0):

Você deve realizar apenas uma clausula from e atribuir alias para cada uma das "tabelas", que na verdade são chamadas de funções que retornam uma tabela. Todavia não parece fazer muito sentido essa query, você precisa utilizar a clausula from mesmo?

Recomendo se possível não utilizar tantas funções e sim Views, me parece mais correto para o seu caso, pesquise mais sobre Views no PostgreSQL. A vantagem performática da View é que ela é uma leitura dinâmica, você cria uma View e em vez de passar parâmetros utiliza cláusula Where normalmente.

Outra coisa importante é pesquisar sobre JOIN LATERAL ou simplesmente LATERAL, desta forma é possível realizar processamento de dados a nível de Views.